# How to get the build number in Cruise Control .net ccnet.config file?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I can get the Build info from CCNetLabel, which is in format: major.minor.build.revision , I am interested in getting the build number only, is there any variable which I can access to get the build number value?

I can do it by writing a tool, but I am interested in knowing if it is possible to get hold of any property in Cruise Control .net to get this value.

Thanks in Advance.

Tara Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A list of all CruiseControl.Net integration properties](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Integration_Properties). There is no build number variable, you have to parse it yourself. For example, in NAnt you can use [version::get-build()](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/version.get-build.html) to split it, and in MSBuild 4.0 this should work:

```
$(CCNetLabel.Split('.')[2])
```

Comment: Thanks Skolima, I am using nant and wrote a small c# code to split the version number. Do you know any split kind of function available in nant to achieve it, so that i dont need custom tool to split the version label?

Comment: I do, and I mentioned it before in the answer: version::get-build().